# How to download a specific version of the code from RTC?

Tags: rtc

In SVN we have one option to download code on a particular revision. This provides the flexibility to download code on old revision also for build.

Is there a option in RTC to download a code on particular revision?

Answer (score 3):

Yes: once you have done a repo workspace on a stream (where that old version was baselined), you can select a component (in the components section of your workspace), and click on "Replace with".

You can then chose the baseline you want to see, and it will be downloaded if you have a local workspace or sandbox in place.

Simply don't "deliver" to the stream, or you would replace the most recent baseline by an old one.

---

For setting a file to an older version, it is a bit manual (as [in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/67501/can-i-set-the-file-back-to-a-previous-version)):

> Right click on the file in the change set, and select "show history" (or if the file is in an editor, right click on the editor and select "Team -> Show_History). That will open the History view on the file, form which you can select the version you want.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

The only thing that worked for me was:
.

1. On your workspace's tab [**Pending Changes**] -> *RightClick* on the component that you want to get file(s) back -> [**Show**] -> [**History**]
2. *RightClick* on the "*PackOfChanges*"  that has your wanted file(s) -> [**Revert**]
   .

PS: It won't actually revert your actual project state to that day, and won't undo that "commit". The only thing that it does is showing on your workspace's tab [**Pending Changes**] all the diferences between that day and you actual code, and in every file(s) that you want back you:

3. "*DoubleClick*" the file that you want back that was showed by revert, and an Editor will appear with the diferences between you file's actual code and it self on that day, and you pass all the code from the right to the left.
4. After it's done, on your workspace's tab [**Pending Changes**], *RightClick* on the *RevertPackage* -> *Remove*
   .

Have a nice day!